# If you only accept credit card payments, are there any functions that can not be done with src_xxxx but only with tok_xxxx?

Tags: stripe-payments

**Can all the functions that can be done with tok_xxxx be done with src_xxxx?**

Even if you specify tok_xxxx or src_xxxx, it will be used by linking to the Customer object, so in the end is not the same thing?

Is checkout.js the only feature that can not be done with 'src_xxxx'?

---

**The following PHP code works as expected, but is it better to use 'src_xxxx'?**

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxx");

\Stripe\Customer::create([
    "source" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
]);

\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 777,
  "customer" => $customer->id,
  "currency" => "USD",
));
```

---

If you would like to make a one-time payment, is it better to use 'tok_xxxx'?

If you want to associate a customer with a one-time payment, is it better to 'src_xxxx'?

Isn't it recommended to implement everything with 'src_xxxx', as it is cumbersome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some background on Sources/Token in Stripe's World.

Source in Stripe's concept is a payment method such as Credit Card, Bank Transfer, ATH, Alipay, WeChat Pay etc.

And for "Credit Card" payment, Token and Source can be safely used interchangeably. Basically it is a secure and PCI compliant way to pass Credit Card information between systems.

Source/Token are one-time-use only, this one time use can be a "Charge" or "Attach to Customer". Once you've charged the source or attach the source to a customer, the source/token will become "consumed". 
When you use "consumed" source again such as charge the source or attach the source to the customer, you will see "invalid_request_error" .

So how does Stripe do recurring charges allowing user using stored card? 
The high level workflow will be 
Create a source -> Attach the source to the customer -> Charge the customer with the source id AND customer id

meaning you will need to save/attach the source to the customer to make the source "reusable". And it is required that you need to use the Source ID together with Customer ID. And if you do not provide source id and use only Customer ID, the default source of the customer will be used.

Saying all that, to your question:
If you would like to make a one-time payment, is it better to use 'tok_xxxx'?

> You could use either token or source, you could create source or token using stripe Checkout or Elements.

If you want to associate a customer with a one-time payment, is it better to 'src_xxxx'?

> Yes, you will have to save a token/source to the customer. When you charge the customer, the transaction will appear under the customer

Isn't it recommended to implement everything with 'src_xxxx', as it is cumbersome?

> If you are using non-credit card payment such as ACH, Alipay and 3DS etc, source is required. But for normal credit card, it does not have any difference between token and source.

Comment: ” normal credit card, it does not have any difference between token and source.”I understood it well. The question was solved thanks.